# Finding everything but anchor tags within a <p> tag with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have several HTML blocks on a page set up like:

```
<p class="something">
    <a href="http://example.com/9999">text 1 2 3</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/2346saasdf">text 3 4 5</a>
    (9999)
    <a href="http://example.com/sad3ws">text 5 6 7random</a>
</p>
```

I want to get the digit that is in the parentheses, with them. I have to admit I've never really used regex before -- read about it, seen examples of it but haven't used it myself. Anyway, I created this with a little bit of looking around:

`<p class="something">(.*?)</p>`

That correctly gets the entire `<p>` block, but again, I just want the `(9999)` (with parentheses intact). I'm not really sure how to get it.

Assuming that other elements on the page could also have digits in parentheses (but they won't be included in this exact format), and that the HTML will remain valid and consistent, how can I get it?

I understand this is probably easy for someone who has used regex before, but for the solution, I'd appreciate a little detail on what each character captures so I can learn from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I've read that before, along with Jeff's post on his blog. Parsing [X]HTML is the devil *if* you're trying to parse everything. If it's like my situation, where the content is valid and consistent, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Just because it's a limited case where regex *might* work doesn't mean it's the right tool. Using a straightforward parser (or just looking at the DOM properly) would most likely be shorter *and* easier to maintain later.

Comment: It *could* be done with a regex in a language that supports infinite repetition inside lookbehind. This would be extremely inefficient, but it would work. However, only .NET and JGSoft support this currently (as far as I know); JavaScript doesn't even support fixed-length lookbehind, so there's no way to match just `(9999)` in your example.

Comment: @Tim Really? That's interesting. Actual facts are a lot more helpful than, "parsing HTML with regex is the devil!!" or the other saying, "... now you have two problems." This was meant as sort of a learning exercise for me, I wasn't trying to spark a debate on when not to use regex. The problem is, that SO answer and several blog posts have created such a following, that anything that has "HTML" and "regex" in the same sentence is "omg don't do it, you'll destroy a third world country and kill 50 kittens every time invalid syntax breaks your patterns!1" I'm fully aware HTML+regex has problems.

Comment: One thing that also bothers me: people come to SO asking "I have [x tools] and I need to get [y output], what can I do?" I see a lot of "you're making your life too complicated! Use [z tool]!" (This answer is an example, but I see it on so many questions). Usually they're using the tool for a reason, like company policy -- which is greeted with comments like "your boss is an idiot, ask for [z tool] or quit your job!" In this case, I can't use jQuery because I'm making a bookmarklet for a static HTML page. Yet, it's the top voted answer, because somehow Javascript questions === jQuery.

Comment: Sorry I'm being a bit melodramatic here; the responses that this question has garnered are frustrating. I just get annoyed when I see this behavior on other questions, and now it's happened on one of my own.

Comment: @Corey: you're missing the point, you obviously don't understand what tools are available to you, and of the ones *already available* you're picking the *wrong* one. FWIW, I've updated my answer with a non-jQuery solution that still uses the DOM, and *no* regex.

Comment: @Corey: Read the [Regular Expression Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694/); it has a section on matching HTML/XML etc. with regular expressions and explains very well what can and what can't be done. Basically there are two things that bite you: a) arbitrarily nested structures - by definition irregular; if you know the maximum level of nesting you *could* compensate in your regex, but [it'll be ugly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856790/regex-filter-for-stl-messages/3858028#3858028). b) delimiters might be inside strings or comments, and only a parser can catch those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Instead, use an HTML parser, then simply read the text (non-tag) content within the desired `<p>` block.

jQuery is a pretty decent HTML parser, so you can get the desired text stored in a variable `x` using:

```
var x = $('p').clone().find('a').remove().end().text();
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WdmZN/)

If you can't use jQuery to make your life easy for whatever reason, you can use raw JavaScript at the DOM:

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].cloneNode(true);
var x = "";
for(var k in y.childNodes){ 
    if(y.childNodes[k].nodeType == 3){ 
        x += y.childNodes[k].textContent; 
    }
}
x = x.trim();
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WdmZN/3/)

Comment: I'm not trying to parse the entire internet. I'm only parsing one page where its content will remain consistent.

Comment: @Corey, if you choose to use a regex, you're still doing it the hard way.

Comment: @Corey: The easiest way to do this is with an HTML parser, and that's particularly easy in JavaScript since the browser does all the heavy lifting. (see my edited post for an example of how trivial it is)

Answer (score 1):

With most regex engines, parenthesis means grouping parts of the expression, not matching parenthesis in the input.

As such, this (which you say work, somewhat):

```
<p class="something">(.*?)</p>
                     ^   ^
                     |   |
                     +---+--- creates a group
```

Since this "works", you can just extract the contents of that group, but that would give you the parenthesis as well.

I would try this:

```
<p class="something">\((.*?)\)</p>
                     ^^     ^^
                      |     |
                      +-----+-- matches (...)
```

And then extract the contents of the first group.

Now, as for what each character means:

```
<p class="something">\((.*?)\)</p>

<p class="something">                 match <p class="something">
                     \(               match (, without the \ it would be a group
                       (              create a group
                        .             match one character (usually not newlines)
                         *            ... repeated zero or more times
                          ?           ... in a non-greedy way
                           )          end the group
                            \)        match )
                              </p>    match </p>
```

Comment: You look like you really, *really* want to use `(?x)` mode. ☺

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what is `(?x)` mode?

Comment: If you mean "code mode", then yes, I love that formatting, if you check out some of my other answers you'll see that I take advantage of it *a lot*. For instance, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome/5754#5754 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges/143568#143568

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Regex, the following pattern might work for you.

```
var re = /<\/a>\s*([^\s]+)\s*<a /ig;
```